# Can I use aiozmq with aiohttp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zeromq, python-asyncio

I want to offer an asynchronous http server to clients, and use asynchronous pub-sub on an internal network of peers to which those clients connect.

It looks like the best libraries for this, respectively, are aiohttp and aiozmq:

```
import aiohttp
import aiozmq
```

If I do the above, am I already doing it wrong?

It is like using different asynchronous frameworks at once...

Comment: // , Do you actually have a specific comment? :P But it's not a specific problem. Just a specific question. If I put A and B together, will bad things happen

Comment: Did you try it? Did bad things happen? Do you have any particular reason to think they *might*? Speculation isn't very useful, if you have a [mcve] of a problem that's a better starting point. And, again, please cut it out.

Answer (score 4):

Since both libraries use the `asyncio` framework, they should have no problems cooperating, even if they were not *specifically* written with one another in mind.

Such cooperation is an important part of the motivation to create asyncio in the first place, prompted by a previously fragmented playing field of asynchronous frameworks and event loops.

Comment: // , The limited and second hand traumatizing experience of that very "previously fragmented playing field of asynchronous frameworks" is exactly why I asked this. Plus, with stuff like this it's easy to write 1000 or 10k lines of code before running into some kind of scaling issue with async, thanks for the tip. I'll look through both their docs again too.